# Webpack: How to avoid the renaming of exported functions?

Tags: node.js, webpack, export

I have a NodeJS application that will be an AWS Lambda.

The main JS file for the app is app.js.

I also have a ./lib/index.js which is the main library, and includes all other reference library code.

My thought was that I'd set WebPack to utilize the ./lib/index.js as the entry and create a new ./lib/index.js which is a composite of all the referenced dependencies/files.

I ran WebPack on this, worked through some small issues; and I have the new ./lib/index.js.

The problem is that the main Lambda code has the following:

```
const lib           = require('./lib/index');
...
lib.runRoutines(date);
```

WebPack seems to rename the lib.runRoutines to some new name I have no idea what it is, nor is it simple to find within the code.

Is there a way to keep WebPack from renaming exported functions, at least for the top level library?

---------- UPDATED TO ADD webpack config ----------------
I've tried the TerserPlugin, but I'm either utilizing it improperly, or something else is wrong, as there still isn't a "runRoutine" function anywhere within the created JavaScript file.

The following is my current webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin");
const TerserPlugin  = require('terser-webpack-plugin')
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/lib/index.js',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
        fallback: {
            "fs": false,
            "tls": false,
            "net": false,
            "dns": false,
            "child_process": false,
            "dtrace-provider": false
        }
    },
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({
                terserOptions: {
                    keep_classnames: true,
                    keep_fnames: true
                }
            })
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'index.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'lib'),
    },
    plugins: [
        new NodePolyfillPlugin(),
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin({resourceRegExp: /.sql$/ })
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Terser Plugin.

per [How to disable in Webpack to rename of function names? TypeScript, Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42300147/how-to-disable-in-webpack-to-rename-of-function-names-typescript-javascript#answer-56723206):

> Terser configuration for webpack.conf:

```
optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
        new TerserPlugin({
            terserOptions: {
                keep_classnames: true,
                keep_fnames: true
            }
          })
        ]
  },
```

See the [Terser Plugin Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42300147/how-to-disable-in-webpack-to-rename-of-function-names-typescript-javascript#answer-56723206) for available options.

Comment: Thank-you for this example. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I'm still seeing the functions renamed. I posted my Webpack config if anything obvious jumps out.

Comment: I got that part working. Thank-you. It was other errors I had.